# InputStreamReader should end if there are no more lines

Tags: java, stream

I have an `InputStreamReader` (which is combined with a `BufferedReader`).

I want to read the content of the Stream in a loop

```
while((line = MyStream.readLine()) != null) {
    s.o.p(line);
    String lastline; 
}
```

but this creates a loop without an end, so my whole program waits for the loop to end .. and waits ... and waits.

At the moment, I've got a method where you can say how many lines should be read. This works fine, but is very inflexible.

My method at the moment

```
public void getStatus(int times) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        System.out.println(fromServer.readLine());
    }
```

I  want this method to read all lines and save the last one in a string without the "times" parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you've got will work *if* it reaches the end of a stream.

My guess is that this is a network stream, and the other end isn't closing the connection. That won't end up with you going into the loop ad infinitum though - it'll end up with you just hanging on the `readLine` call, waiting for either the other end to close the stream, or for more data to arrive.

You need to *either* have some way of detecting you're finished (e.g. a terminating line / the connection closing) *or* know how many lines to read ahead of time.

Comment: +1. Jon's right - the situation you find yourself in isn't that the reader has reached the end of the stream, but that it's blocking for more input *because it doesn't know* if it's at the end of the stream yet.  There is no way around this from the Java side - if the end of the stream hasn't been reached, your reader cannot know if there are more lines to come.

Comment: yeah, its a network stream. didn't get that this will change the situation